# Does getting zarya's pixel spray have to be non-stop charge or just a total of 60 seconds?

Tags: achievements, overwatch

The description for it is: "Maintain 70 or over charge for 60 seconds", but I'm not sure if it has to be continuous or a total of 60 seconds

Answer (score 6):

It must be 60 seconds continuous. If you drop below 70, the timer is reset.

Pixel sprays are used to reward a difficult achievement with a specific action on a specific character, having a total of 60 seconds over 70 charge is fairly easy in the long term.